# Поиск файла из массива по части его имени

Tags: java, массивы, arraylist

Есть мапа TreeMap, она передаёт данные в массив. В массиве данные сортируются, тут все хорошо. Надо сделать такой метод, чтобы брал только 5 штук из массива после сортировки которые начинаются на заданные буквы.

Например, ввёл abc и тебе он вернул список из 5 значений, которые начинаются с abc.

Главное, чтобы ровно 5 значений и порядок файлов не сбился(они уже отсортированы по дате\алфавиту)

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {



    TreeMap<File, Class> classesByFiles = find("com.company", ""); // получил мапу
    List<File> files = new ArrayList<>(classesByFiles.keySet()); //получил список файлов из мапы
    Collections.sort(files, MODIFIED_DATE_FILE_COMPARATOR);// посортировал




    for (File file : files) // идем по массиву
         {
        System.out.println(file);// выводим его на печать для проверки
         }
```

Comment: а в чём именно вопрос? И зачем создавать массив, в `TreeMap` ключи тоже отсортированы.

Comment: @pavel В ' Treemap ' они отсортированы по алфавиту, а нам нужно в первую очередь по дате последнего изменения. Суть вопроса в том чтобы достать из уже сортированного массива всего 5 значений начинающихся на введёные символы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот как-то так

```
List<File> abc = files.stream().filter(f -> f.getName().startsWith("abc"))
            .limit(5).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Либо так

```
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidArgumentException {
        List<File> files = new ArrayList<>();
        files.add(new File("C:/test/"));
        files.add(new File("abc1"));
        files.add(new File("abc2"));
        files.add(new File("abc3"));
        files.add(new File("weabc4"));
        files.add(new File("abc5"));
        files.add(new File("sdabc5"));
        files.add(new File("abc4"));
        Collections.sort(files);

        String startName = "abc";
        List<File> files1 = getFiles(files, startName);
        files1.forEach(f -> System.out.println(f.getName()));
    }

    public static List<File> getFiles(List<File> files, String startName){
        List<File> listFiles = new ArrayList<>();
        for (File file : files) {
            if(file.getName().startsWith(startName))
                listFiles.add(file);
        }

        if(listFiles.size() > 5)
            return listFiles.subList(0, 5);

        return listFiles;

    }

}
```

Comment: Красным подчёркивает stream, getName и Collectors

Comment: это настройки твоего IDE, ALT + Enter  и покажет тебе мол добавить в исключение и импортировать Collectors

Comment: Нет такого импорта. Это не восьмая джава случаем? На 7 все остальное написано.

Comment: эх. 8-ая. завтра напишу другой код

Comment: @Dmitrii прости, не получается нормально добавить код ((